# Redis : Is it possible to get filtered data by any field stored in Redis?

Tags: mysql, redis, key-value, key-value-store, nosql

I mean I have rows like say

```
id name email     emp_id
1  abc  abc@a.com e1e2
2  lmn  lmn@a.com e1e3
```

And after fetching mysql, I stored this data in redis.

Now say I want to fetch data by someone's email id say `abc@a.com` from redis, How do I do that and what data type should I use in redis?

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you are storing the data in redis. If you're frequently accessing via email then you could use the email as the key of a hash, and access the value directly with something like 'HGETALL email:abc@a.com'.

Comment: What if I want to search by fname and lname too? There are say 50 columns in a table, we cant make 50 different keys on one table! And there are more than 100 tables in any application.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a secondary index. You can implement it on your own using redis data structures. Or if you're okay with redis 4.0 (in RC stage right now), you can try this module that allows you to automate that:

https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/secondary

Using it you can do something like:

```
IDX.FROM users_email WHERE "email ='abc@a.com'" HGETALL $
```

And perform redis operations on keys matching the WHERE condition (the `$` gets substituted for the actual id for each id that matches the query).